# SAS proc sgplot with date axis formatted as m/d/yy (i.e. without leading zeros)

Tags: formatting, sas, axis, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with SAS proc sgplot and format the xaxis to be m/d/yy (for example 1/1/06).  I created a custom date format like this:

```
PICTURE myDateFmt low-high = '%m/%d/%0y' (DATATYPE = date);
```

Then I formatted my date variable to be this format in a data step, and put this line in my proc sgplot step:

```
xaxis offsetmin = 0 offsetmax = 0 display=(nolabel) tickvalueformat=data;
```

However, when I do this, the date axis text all just disappears. Does anyone know of a way to format the date axis in a plot to be m/d/yy format?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the TICKVALUEFORMAT option must have a problem with picture formats.  When I tried this, my graph displayed "%m/%d/%0y" on the x-axis.  But if I print the data, the formatted values are as desired so I think the picture format is created correctly.

I did a work-around where I created a value format for the date range of interest and then used that in the SGPLOT.  To do this, I had to generate a dataset with one record for each day in the range of interest, and then converted that dataset to a format.  Not ideal, but it works.

Hope this helps.

```
proc format;
    PICTURE myDateFmt 
        low-high = '%m/%d/%0y' (DATATYPE = date)
;
run;

*** TEST DATA TO EXPERIMENT WITH - SPANS YEAR 1987 ***;
data stocks;
    set sashelp.stocks;
    where (mdy(1,1,1987) <= date <= mdy(12,31,1987));
    format date myDateFmt. ;
run;

title 'USER CREATED PICTURE FORMAT DOES NOT WORK';
proc sgplot data=work.stocks;
    scatter x=date y=close;
    xaxis offsetmin = 0 offsetmax = 0 display=(nolabel) tickvalueformat=data;
run;


title 'SAS SUPPLIED FORMAT DOES WORK'; 
proc sgplot data=work.stocks;
    scatter x=date y=close;
    xaxis offsetmin = 0 offsetmax = 0 display=(nolabel) tickvalueformat=monyy5.;
run;


*** RECREATE FORMAT FOR SPECIFIC DATE RANGE THAT MATCHES DATA AND GRAPH AXIS DESIRED ***;
*** THIS WILL CREATE A FORMAT ENTRY FOR EVERY DAY IN THE RANGE ***;
data cntldate;
    fmtname = 'myDateN';
    type = 'n';
    *** HARD CODE START/END DATES TO MATCH GRAPH AXIS DESIRED ***;
    do start = mdy(1,1,1987) to mdy(1,1,1988);
        *** FORMAT LABEL WILL BE DATE FORMAT WITHOUT LEADING ZEROS ***;
        label = strip (put(start, myDateFmt.) );
        output;
    end;
run;

*** CONVERT CONTROL DATASET TO A FORMAT ***;
proc format library=work cntlin=cntldate;
run;


title 'USER CREATED VALUE FORMAT WORKS';
title2 'NOTE: HARDCODE OF START/END VALUE FOR XAXIS, OTHERWISE SAS MAY SELECT AXIS ENDPOINT OUTSIDE OF FORMAT RANGE';
title3 'NOTE2: AXIS MAY NOT REPORT EVERY MONTH DUE TO SPACE ISSUES';
proc sgplot data=work.stocks;
    scatter x=date y=close;
    xaxis offsetmin = 0 offsetmax = 0 display=(nolabel) tickvalueformat=myDateN.
        values=('1jan87'd to '1jan88'd by month);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Sunny! I should have mentioned that I'm doing this for a large number of charts, and I would prefer that SAS automatically chooses which date values to put on the axis. So hardcoding the start end date and the interval would not be very efficient.  But I appreciate this..

Comment: If you really want this format for your graphs, you can still use the code above.  Just change the DO loop in the CNTLDATA dataset to run a few years before and after the date range in your data.  An extreme thing to do would be to generate the DO loop for every day between 1900-2099.  Then in the SGPLOT, you won’t need to hard code any min/max specifications for the xaxis, and when SAS choose the values it wants for the xaxis of each plot, the format values will exist.  Just a suggestion for your consideration.  Good luck with your graphs!

Comment: that sounds great!! i will try that next. thank you sunny.